# Is it insecure to make the render engine render html instead of jade?

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic-angular project. In my mean stack, I want to set the engine to render html instead of jade. In my opinion it is simpler to code, but I am not sure if it is safe.

Comment: What do you mean *"render html instead of jade"*? Jade is a templating engine that renders to HTML. If you want a server-side dynamic page, you need to use a templating engine. If you are looking for a templating engine that more closely resembles HTML, you can have a look at [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: I think my question wasn’t clear. I want to redirect to a html page. For example, after a login method I call something like this: “res.redirect(‘initialPage.html’);”. I know it is possible, but is it safe?

Comment: Yes that is safe, it is just a static HTML file.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!